# ubuntu: uninstall matplotlib with pip won't work

Tags: python, ubuntu, matplotlib, pip

I'm on Ubuntu and I neeed to **uninstall** `matplotlib`, which I installed as an ubuntu package and later upgraded with `pip`. 
The usual command doesn't work:

```
$ sudo pip uninstall matplotlib
Can't uninstall 'matplotlib'. No files were found to uninstall.
```

What should I do?

Extra info:

```
~$ pip matplotlib --version
ERROR: unknown command "matplotlib"
me@me:~$ pip show matplotlib
---
Name: matplotlib
Version: 1.4.0
Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Requires: numpy, six, python-dateutil, pyparsing, nose, mock, nose, mock

$ pip --version
pip 1.5.4 from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python 2.7)
```

Comment: How did you install matplotlib? Does `pip --version` show it's for the same python installation matplotlib is installed for?

Comment: (`pip --version`, not `pip matplotlib --version`...)  Although if `pip show` is finding the package it's probably using the right python installation...

Comment: I might have installed it first as an ubuntu package and then upgraded it with pip. Now I removed the ubuntu package, but matplotlib is still importable. :/

Comment: If you installed via Apt, `sudo apt-get remove python-matplotlib`.

Comment: If nothing else, you can probably just remove the package directory within dist-packages manually.

Comment: Ok, I deleted the folder in the package directory and tha did the trick.
My whole point was to (re)install matplotlib 1.3.1, since 1.4 was incompatible with some plots I had. The `__version__` attribute of `matplotlib` says it's 1.3.1, which is correct, but `pip` still says it's 1.4. For now it works, I just hope it won't cause any problems in the future.

Comment: @RickyRobinson What plots are broken in 1.4 and have you reported them as bugs?

Comment: No, I haven't reported it, sorry.
Anyways, I pickle plots on a server running CentOS, where the latest version of matplotlib I could install was 1.3.0. I later view the plots on my laptop, where I run Ubuntu and where I have matplotlib 1.3.1. Its warns me that it's not the same version with which the plots were saved, but works fine. With matplotlib 1.4 it seems that I can't load the pickled plots: http://pastebin.com/t8Q7kxKv

Comment: Interesting...I would not naively classify that as a bug as I don't think we make any claims that unpickling should be backwards compatible, and don't think we should as it depends in the internals of the mpl objects which is something we need to preserve the ability to change.

Answer (score 0):

With pip you have installed matplotlib as a user not as root. This means when you try to uninstall it as root it is not recognised as installed (because it isn't).

You need to uninstall it with user level access thus drop the "sudo"

So your pip commands should look like this:

```
$pip uninstall matplotlibpip
```

instead of:

```
$sudo pip uninstall matplotlib
```

Answer (score 0):

For uninstall package for python3 in ubuntu (pip3)
pip only for python 2.7 in ubuntu

first upgrade pip ( pip or pip3 )

```bash
$> pip/pip3 install --upgrade pip/pip3
```

And

```bash
$> pip3/pip uninstall package
```

if not work

```bash
$> sudo su -

$> pip3/pip uninstall package
```

And not work again

```bash
$> sudo su -

$> apt autoremove python-matplotlib
```

And if you start new project use **venv**!
see [**This Link!**](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-setup-virtual-environments-in-python/)